# Improve Code - Web Scraping Job Offers - Title, Employer, Salary, Link required

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I wrote a web-scraping code that scans all the pages in a Job Portal and report the job offers that satisfy the salary requirement in the function. The important fields for me are the Job Title, the Employer, the Salary, and the Link. I am using now a getText() method, but takes all the elements.
the result looks like:

```
Zubný lekár/lekárka DENTAL CARE Dr. Rosa, s. r. o.Námestie sv. Františka, Karlova Ves


        Od 4 500 EUR/mesiac
    

Pridané Pred 4 dňami  Pridať k vybraným   
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/dental-care-dr-rosa/O3863429
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/dental-care-dr-rosa/O3863429


Head of Core Technology DevelopmentESET, spol. s r.o.Bratislava


        4 500 EUR/mesiac
    

Pridané pred 2 týždňami  Pridať k vybraným   
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/eset/C22141
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/eset/O3933805
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/eset/O3933805
```

It takes two unnecessary items and duplicate the link (as there are 2 to 3 links in <a 'href' )Any better idea?

```
def search4job(salary):
    import bs4, requests, re
    #Classes -> employer: class='employer'>
    # -> salary ".label"
    # -> Job Title class='title'
    # -> TODO: link 
    base_url= 'https://www.profesia.sk/praca/bratislava/plny-uvazok/?languages=73&page_num={}'
    page = 1 #to start from page1
    request = requests.get(base_url.format(page)) #to take complete url
    HTML = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml') 
    pattern = r'(\d\s\d\d\d)' #salary pattern

    while len(HTML.select(".list-row"))>0: 
        #in pages without job offer the len of list-row is 0, iterates until there are no job offers
        
        #iteration within the page, return Job Details
        for i in HTML.select(".list-row"):
            #to give result only when there's a salary shown
            if i.find('span',{'class':'label-group'}):
                try:
                    #to give result only if the salary is higher than the one i want
                    if int(str(re.search(pattern,str(i.find('span',{'class':'label-group'}))).group()).replace(" ",""))>=salary:
                        #print Job Details
                        print(i.getText())
                        #print job offer link
                        try:
                            for link in i.findAll('a',attrs={'href':re.compile("/praca/")}):
                                print('https://www.profesia.sk'+str(link.get('href')))
                        except:
                            print("There is an error")
                        print('\n')  #new line between job offers
                except:
                    pass
        #iteration over the pages
        page +=1
        request = requests.get(base_url.format(page))
        HTML = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text,'lxml')
        #RESTART UNTIL THERE ARE JOB OFFERS

search4job(4000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script to scrape data from Profesia:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url= 'https://www.profesia.sk/praca/bratislava/plny-uvazok/?languages=73&page_num={}'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

page = 1
while True:
    print(base_url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url.format(page)).content, 'html.parser')

    links = soup.select('h2 > a')

    if not links:
        break

    for l in links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.profesia.sk' + l['href']).content, 'html.parser')

        job_title = soup.h1.text
        employer = soup.select_one('[itemprop="hiringOrganization"]')
        employer = employer.text if employer else '-'
        salary = soup.select_one('span[class^="salary"]')
        salary = salary.text if salary else '-'

        print(job_title)
        print(employer)
        print(salary)
        print('https://www.profesia.sk' + l['href'])
        print('-' * 80)

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/bratislava/plny-uvazok/?languages=73&page_num=1
Front Office Manager - AC Hotel by Marriott Bratislava Old Town
Legendhotels Slovakia, s.r.o.
From 1 800 EUR/month
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/legendhotels-slovakia/O3955894
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Catalog Quality Associate - Polish & Spanish
Amazon /Slovakia/ s.r.o.
1 150 EUR/month
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/amazon-slovakia/O3937464
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Financial Manager - AC Hotel by Marriott Bratislava Old Town
Legendhotels Slovakia, s.r.o.
From 2 200 EUR/month
https://www.profesia.sk/praca/legendhotels-slovakia/O3955853
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, thank you for taking this, appreciated. I'd have some questions on your code (i am a noob in python and programming in general):

1)  I found the classes by clicking on "inspect", but i notice you picked elements i was not able to find, like: "[itemprop="hiringOrganization"]". Besides the experience, how do you know that there are other elements than the one shown?

2) I didn't really get what the ['href'] part does here:
 soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.profesia.sk' + l['href']).content, 'html.parser'). Can you explain?

3) I like how tidy is your print!

Comment: @AdrianoPatruno 1) I did `print(soup)` and redirected it to the file and then inspected it. 2) `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.profesia.sk' + l['href']).content, 'html.parser')` Here I create new soup from the relative URL stored in `l['href']` (so I need to prepend it with `'https://www.profesia.sk'`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What i miss from your code is my initial aim to filter only the job offers with salary higher than the input, but can be adjusted.